# Ion datetime not displaying well on modal

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework

I have an issue when the modals opens, not displays like in this example: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime the last one that opens the modal with the ion datetime.

```
    <ion-item id="open-modal">
        <ion-icon slot="start" name="calendar-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>choose date</ion-label>
        <ion-text>
          20-6-6
        </ion-text>
      </ion-item>

  <ion-modal trigger="open-modal">
    <ng-template>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-datetime></ion-datetime>
      </ion-content>
    </ng-template>
  </ion-modal>
```

Info:

[Ionic version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRvSt.png)

[The issue itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWuCW.png)

[Ipad size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmF2z.png)

Answer (score 0):

IS'T OK (both android and ios) using:
"@ionic/core": "^6.0.1-dev.1640104484.e62df80",
"@ionic/vue": "^6.0.1-dev.1640104484.e62df80",
"@ionic/vue-router": "^6.0.1-dev.1640104484.e62df80",

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).